# HeidiSQL: Import CSV

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, import, csv

A few lines of my CSV:

```
"id","date","date_","pow","ene","reac"
"ES0134000563024539AM0F","2013-05-02","2013-06-05","62","43","43"
"ES0134000573024539AM0F","2013-05-02","2013-06-05","62","43","43"
"ES0134000563224539AM0F","2013-05-02","2013-06-05","62","43","43"
```

I tried to import text file but I've received an **error message with code 1261**. I used the following control characters:

- Fields terminated by: `"`
- Fields enclosed by: `,`
- Fields escaped by: `"`
- Lines terminated by: `\r\n`

Comment: Try no enclosing and terminating with comma, I would also check all the columns have complete data.

Comment: Your fields are terminated by `,` not by `"`.

Comment: And enclosed by `"`.  It is unclear whether "escaped" is set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) your error is:

> Error: 1261 SQLSTATE: 01000 (ER_WARN_TOO_FEW_RECORDS)
>   Message: Row %ld doesn't contain data for all columns

Thus it appears that your table have more column than the file. You will have to specify the column-names explicitly. Also the remaining columns should be nullable. (You might want to share table definition if below command doesn't work)

**Try this:**

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file' INTO TABLE your_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (id,date,date_,pow,ene,reac);`

If you are interested you might want to refer this blog post which explains various use-cases for [loading delimited data to mysql](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/load-delimited-data-csv-excel-into-mysql-server).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mysql_user and @oNare for your answers and I do it:

- Fields terminated by: `,`
- Fields enclosed by: `"`
- Lines terminated by: `\r\n`

When I tried to do that with MySQL Workbench 6.3 and Table Data Import Wizard, I couldn't believe it because it is so slow. And I tried to do it with HeidiSQL and is faster than MySQL Workbench but no enough. My CSV is a big file (59GB) and the problem is the time to load those data.

Sorry for my English. It is not my native language. Thanks.